# Pentaho Data Integration - Multiple CSV File Inputs

Tags: csv, pentaho

I've been using Pentaho Data Integration lately and currently I intend to use it to a project I'm in. The assist I'm looking for is the following:

- There can be variable CSV file inputs in a folder

Is there a way to get all .csv files (the operator/ series of operators) using Pentaho?

After this step I believe what I have to do is pretty simple, as I only have to merge those files together.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Text File Input. It allows for folders using a regular expression and can handle csv files

Answer (score 0):

Add the "Get File Names" step before the "CSV file input" step.  When the CSV step has input, then a field appears in the configuration dialog allowing you to get the filename from the incoming stream.